# What all configuration is required for logstash to work

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, elastic-stack

I want to have ELK stack of which i have installed elasticsearch and Kibana on one machine and logstash on one machine below is my logstash file name as logstash.conf at this location /etc/logstash/conf.d with following configuration

```
input {
  stdin {}
  file {
    type => syslog
    path => "/u01/workspace/data/tenodata/logs/teno.log"
    start_position => end
  }
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
  elasticsearch {
       hosts => ["172.3.9.5:9200"]
  }
}
```

but some how it is not able to connect to elasticsearch

can some help me on this and also what is the location of elasticsearch log

Answer (score 0):

[`path.logs`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/important-settings.html#path-settings) property in the `elasticsearch.yml` file (found in the config folder of wherever you installed ES, possibly `/etc/elasticsearch`) will point to where you can find logs. (for me its `/var/log/elasticsearch`)

I would check connectivity from the machine, maybe run `curl 172.3.9.5:9200` and see if it spits back anything. If it just hangs try looking at your security groups to make sure traffic is allowed.

If that's good, make sure that elasticsearch is set to listen for connections from the outside world. By default its set to only bind to localhost, you can edit the [`network.host`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/important-settings.html#network.host) property in the `elasticsearch.yml` and set it to `0.0.0.0` to see if that works. (just fyi if your using the ec2-discovery plugin you would set it to `_ec2_`